# 'rewrite_rules_array' or 'generate_rewrite_rules' for adding custom rewrite rules?

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

Is there any reason why I should use `rewrite_rules_array` instead of `generate_rewrite_rules`?

`generate_rewrite_rules` works out of the box, but I couldn't get `rewrite_rules_array` to work.

And I am told that any array actions [when adding custom rewrite rules] should be done via `rewrite_rules_array` and the rest of `*_rewrite_rule` filters (e.g. `add_rewrite_rule`). It's unclear why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possibly a matter of opinion, but I would say - neither. If you're simply adding new rules, use [`add_rewrite_rule`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) hooked to the `init` action.